Unresolved symbol list: shm_open
I working with vxWorks 6.9 project DKM (Downloadable Kernel Module), Hardware is: PLC Melsec R12CCPU-V, Language: C++, IDE: CW Workbench (WindRiver 3.3).
I want to shared memory between multiple task using shm_open() & mmap(). When build it's no error, but when download and run debug, it's warning: "shm_open unresolved symbol list".
PLC Melsec R12CCPU-V already support INCLUDE_POSIX_SHM & INLUDE_POSIX_MAPPED_FILES, and I tried to include it in configAll.h but not success. I dont find any way to edit vxWorks image or BSP, do you any idea please help.
Here my code:
#include <vxWorks.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysLib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int producer ()
    {
    int   fd;
    int   ix;
    int * pData;
    
    /* create a new SHM object */

    fd = shm_open("/myshm", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    if (fd == -1)
        exit (1);

    /* set object size */

    if (ftruncate (fd, 0x1000) == -1)
        exit (1);

    /* Map shared memory object in the address space of the process */

    pData = (int *) mmap (0, 0x1000,  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                          MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    if (pData == (int *) MAP_FAILED)
        exit (1);

    /* close the file descriptor; the mapping is not impacted by this */

    close (fd);

    /* The mapped image can now be written via the pData pointer */

    for (ix = 0; ix < 25; ix++)
        *(pData + ix) = ix;

    /* unmap shared memory object */

    munmap ((void *)pData, 0x1000);
    }



unresolved symbol always means the code is fine but the linker couldn't find the library.  Do you have the commands you used to compile the code?

If you encounter the undefined reference to 'shm_open' error when compiling C++ code on a Linux system, it typically indicates that the real-time library (-lrt), which provides the shm_open function, is not linked during the compilation process.
Solution
You need to link the -lrt library during the compilation. Here is an example using g++:
g++ -o your_program est.cpp -lrt

